# Wait until .load() is complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to produce a web page that calls in some data via a .load event, then performs a task. I've got a div called `intholder`, and a PHP page that generates some output I want to place into that div. The code I've got is below:

```
var numCol = floor(window.innerWidth / 200);

if(numCol > 5){numCol = 5;}

var colWidth = 100/numCol;

$("#intHolder").load("/scripts/loader.php?n=" + numCol + "&w=" + colWidth);
```

The PHP file then generates a series of `<select>` elements (`numCol` number of them), and fills them with content from a database. Each selection box has a pre-selected value (determined by database queries), and from those, some more content needs loading on the page.

Each selection box has a unique ID (`canvasSeln` where n is incremented), and a value that is contains a 1 digit type designation and a text value for looking up in a database table. Finally, the initial script also generates a series of divs into which this data will go, named `canvasLisn` where n correlates with the selection box. Below is the javascript I've got for that:

```
for (var i=1;i<=$num;i++){ 

        var rawSel = document.getElementById("canvasSel" + i).value;

        var selNow = rawSel.substring(1);
        var selType = parseInt(rawSel.substring(0,1));

        if(selType == 1){
            $("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/profile.php?x=" + selNow);
        }else if(selType == 2){
            $("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/product.php?x=" + selNow);
        }else if(selType == 3){
            $("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/department.php?x=" + selNow);
        }else if(selType == 4){
            $("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/customer.php?x=" + selNow);
        }

}
```

I've tried putting that code into a function triggered by the initial .load callback, but it runs before the objects are painted, so it can't find the values to look up. Is there any way of forcing it to run after the .load has not only completed, but the objects have been painted?

This is the version with callback:

```
var numCol = floor(window.innerWidth / 200);

if(numCol > 5){numCol = 5;}

var colWidth = 100/numCol;

$("#intHolder").load("/scripts/loader.php?n=" + numCol + "&w=" + colWidth, function(){

    for (var i=1;i<=numCol;i++){ 

        var rawSel = document.getElementById("canvasSel" + i).value;

        var selNow = rawSel.substring(1);
        var selType = parseInt(rawSel.substring(0,1));

        if(selType == 1){
            $("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/profile.php?x=" + selNow);
        }else if(selType == 2){
            $("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/product.php?x=" + selNow);
        }else if(selType == 3){
            $("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/department.php?x=" + selNow);
        }else if(selType == 4){
            $("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/customer.php?x=" + selNow);
        }

    }


});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the version of the code where you provided a `.load()` callback. That's the way to do it, so if it didn't work it means you made some mistake. It's impossible to tell what exactly was wrong without seeing that code.

Comment: According to jQuery docs for load: `If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.` Seems like you haven't used the right form of callback, because it should be invoked after the HTML replacement has taken place.

Comment: As a sidenote, conditionally loading scripts based on dynamic elements inserted by other scripts, seems like an error prone and not very good way to create a website ?

Comment: Reduce your callback function to the smallest possible test - perhaps just the for loop and console log i. I'm guessing that $num may not be defined and the callback completes rather quickly. Make sure that you're getting back the values that you expect and watch the console to see those results. Once that is working start adding code back in until all is well.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I just noticed the `$num` thing, it's an overhang from old code. I've changed it to `numCol`, and get the working loop (but it still runs before content loads). I've stripped it right back to just dealing with no loop, and only every looking for the first selection box (which will always be returned), but it still runs before the content loads.

Comment: @adeneo it is, and when I have a free month or so, I'll be rewriting the framework and database on which I've had to base it currently.

Comment: @dmunn it would be impossible for the callback to run before the load is completed. See Chen Asraf's comment above. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Above's the exact code I'm running, and this is the error I get: `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("canvasSel" + i).value')`

Comment: Have you figured out what is returning the null @dmunn?

Answer (score 3):

You say that you tried the callback but you don't show that. Have you tried this form -

```
$("#canvasLis"+ i).load("/scripts/profile.php?x=" + selNow, function() {
    // do stuff when load completes
});
```